SQL Server ignoring the memory limit
I've restricted the memory to 256MB using sp_configure. The box has 13GB and a fresh, OOTB installation, without any databases or tables is hogging up about 5GB, as well as quite a bit of CPU. This is on Ubuntu 220.4. The SQL Server version is SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU15) (KB5041321) - 16.0.4145.4 (X64) Sep 19 2024 08:25:04.
How do I get SQL Server to observe the limit set using sp_configure?
SELECT physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024 AS physical_memory,
       virtual_address_space_committed_kb/1024 AS virtual_address_committed,
       virtual_address_space_reserved_kb/1024 AS virtual_reserved
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;

gives the following:
physical_memory virtual_committed virtual_reserved_MB
      4096                  212            4096


First of all, that instance isn't going to do anything with 256 MB. You're lucky it starts up. Secondly, It's not using 5GB, it committed 212 MB for the engine. Third, SQL on Linux runs a translation layer which won't be accounted for in the SQL Engine memory. This leads me to question, what the actual issue is and why the use of 256 MB which won't do anything?

From here: The max server memory option only limits the size of the SQL Server buffer pool. The max server memory option doesn't limit a remaining unreserved memory area that SQL Server leaves for allocations of other components such as extended stored procedures, COM objects, non-shared DLLs and EXEs. As Sean suggested, this also doesn't account for additional components that are required for SQL Server to run on other platforms, like Ubuntu.
